# Can asynchronous fetch still freeze the browser?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I'm working on a page that has to download a lot of data on initial page load. I initially tried using an asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest`, but I found that the browser was being frozen during while the request was in progress (which was about 3 seconds). I then tried to use the browser's `fetch` API, which is what I am showing below.

```
async function fetch_stuff() {
    for (let i of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) {
        let response = await fetch(`chunk.${i}.json`);
        let data = await response.json();
        Object.assign(combined_data, data);
        refresh_list();
    }
}
```

In addition, I have an event listener in a textinput that updates DOM elements so that the user can see the result of his query.

```
filter_input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    refresh_list();
});
```

The problem is that the page largely freezes while all the downloads are happening, which means the user can't really type into the text box. My guess is that the requests are indeed happening asynchronously, but still overloading the browser somehow so that the page is busy just keeping up with the incoming data.

I'd like to have a long-ish download running in the background while giving the user a smooth experience.

1. Why are asynchronous requests causing a slow user interface?
2. Would running synchronous requests in web workers be any smoother?
3. Am I doing something wrong here to cause this behavior.

Comment: It might be able freeze it on ancient hardware with a huge response to process, or maybe on a phone but that's pretty unlikely. I'm curious, do you have a link to the page? What you describe shouldn't happen in normal conditions.

Comment: What is `refresh_list` doing?

Comment: I don't see any noticeable lag on my laptop or phone. Maybe my hardware can't reproduce it. The issue is probably the DOM manipulation.

Comment: Hmmm, now that I'm asking this question, the problem doesn't seem as bad, but it's still less than ideal. Perhaps the real issue is the large amount of JSON that has to be parsed, since that is not done asynchronously.

Comment: Oh yeah, looks like 5MB worth of stuff? That's quite a lot.